# How to create a timestamp on submit in Django class based views for Update?

Tags: python, django, django-class-based-views

I'm new to class based views in Django and was using a simple UpdateView CBV. The view has many fields that is being displayed on a template, except one; the `Date field`. How do I add a timestamp to this field? The timestamp should be added only the first time the object is created. From the next time onwards, it should only show the timestamp that was added the first time. This is my code:

```
class ReviewsEdit(UpdateView):
    model = ProductReview
    fields = ['title', 'body', 'score', 'responder_name', 'response']     
    template_name = 'review_system/review_edit.html'
    context_object_name = 'review'
```

The `ProductReview` model has all the above fields with another Date field, I'd like to save it with timestamp data when the submit button was clicked - only if it is blank when submitting. Is this possible with CBV?

Comment: Your question is not really clear, do you want to keep the timestamp of the last time the object was updated? If the review is updated, you want to save the timestamp of when the update occured?

Comment: Why do you want to save it only if it is blank? Should it even be editable?

Comment: Sorry about that, yes and no, I want to keep only one timestamp, one that is created when the object is created. Any modifications to the object thereafter will only show the first timestamp and not be updated

Comment: @Risadinha It shouldn't be editable which is why it isn't being displayed in the template.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1230496/621690

Comment: you need to add an updated field on the model  ` updated_on = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)`
so now you have the created and updated fields. You display whichever you choose. The updated field is automatically done by django and saved in the db.

Comment: you should accept the answer below, that should fix your issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got it, I had to over-ride the `save()` method to get it done. It works something like this. After defining your models, over-ride `save()` method.

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
 if not self.your.field:
        self.date_field = datetime.datetime.now()
 super(ModelName, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: What is `your.field`?

Comment: Oh, `your.field` is any field the reader wants to operate on. I thought maybe the community will complain if my answer was too specific, so I made it a little bit generic.

Comment: It's broken code like this. Change it to `self.your_field`. So this is the answer to your question. Might make the question a bit clearer but the use case (and the need for this hack instead of using auto_add_now) is still a bit mysterious to me.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to implement fields that let you know when the object was created and/or last edited you can achieve that with these Django fields:

```
class TouchStampModel(Model):
    created = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
    last_modified = DateTimeField(auto_now=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Any model subclasses will have those fields and they won't be editable by default (won't show up in forms for editing), and `last_modified` will be updated automatically on each DB update while `created` will be set to the DB insert time.

Of course, you can modify your existing model's DateTimeField. There is no need for the superclass unless you have several models that require `created` and `last_modified`.

Comment: Check my question now, is it still confusing? Let me know if it is

Answer (score 2):

```
  class ReviewModel(Model):
       created_at = DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, editable=False, null=False, blank=False)
```

why don't you just display this on the template then.

```
obj.created_at
```

this will always show the time the review was created

Comment: This one will tell me when the entire model was created right? So if a model has many fields, can I also know when individual fields were created with the same line of code?

Comment: say you have `user, body, rating` as part of the model fields, you want to know when each was created....NO to the best of my knowledge as they are all combined at the same time to form the object.